# Node.js filesystem not writing newlines correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I allow the user to write code inside a pre tag, then save whatever is in the pre tag to a file on disk. I am using the following in node/express:

```
fs = require('fs')

fs.writeFile("path_to_file", "string_of_code", 'utf8', function(err) {

})
```

This writes a new file to disk with the code from the pre tag (string_of_code). But it doesn't save the file correctly. The newlines in the pre tag are not captured:

[image]

The black screen is the pre tag, and the white screen is the saved file. I've tried encoding the code_string, and replacing

```
"<br>"
```

with

```
"\n"
```

prior to passing the code_string to node, but the newlines still don't get captured by fs:

```
code_string = encodeURIComponent(strip($('#hold_code_editor').html().replace(/<br>/g, '\n')));
```

This converts this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class data_gather_explore:

    def gather_data(num):
        data = datasets.load_boston()        
        res = 1 + 2
        return(data)
```

to this:

```
mport%20matplotlib.pyplot%20as%20plt%0A%0Aclass%20data_gather_explore%3A%0A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20gather_data(num)%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%20%3D%20datasets.load_boston()%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%C2%A0%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20res%20%3D%201%20%2B%202%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return(data)%0A%0A
```

Comment: Please let me know if you are running nodejs in Windows or Linux. If it's in win, then new line will be \r\n, to be safe you can use the constant os.EOL.

Comment: I am running on a Mac. I am using PyCharm to view the file that is saved.

Comment: Can you paste the exact result of    $('#hold_code_editor').html()  ?

Comment: I added the output of $('#hold_code_editor').html() to my question.

Comment: First thing is that there is no <br>s at that stage, so replacing then is doing nothing. Then, the only suspicious point is the trailing spaces after `data = datasets.load_boston()`. I would try to sanitize the text line by line before giving it to strip function.

Comment: something like this maybe: `code = code.split('\n').map(line => line.replace(/^.*?\s+$/g, ''));`

Comment: Hmm. This only writes the first line of the code in the pre tag.

Comment: Ah, this was my mistake, sorry! split the text into lines then forgot tom join back. But no need to that, the regex can apply globally: `code = code.replace(/^.*?\s+$/g, '');`

Comment: Super close. It's just that when the user presses enter in the pre tag, it doesn't get passed as a newline into node. It gets passed as 4 or 8 spaces :\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162191/discussion-between-hero-qu-and-cybernetic).